# Partial differential equations with octave

Tags: pde, numerical-analysis, octave

I need to find a numerical solution for $-\Delta U = f$, on the $\Omega = [0,1]^2$, with $ U|_{\partial \Omega} = 0$.

I found a method: `POISSONFD` in `NMLibforOctave`
with signature: `[U,X,Y]=POISSONFD(A,C,B,D,NX,NY,FUN,BOUND)`,

but I can't understand how I can specify bound. Something like:

`BOUND = inline('x * y * (y - 1) * (x - 1)', 'x', 'y')`.

This will give good values on the border (I hope). can I use it? Or it's going to be bad? Or may be I should use some other package?

Comment: Are you set on using Octave? Would you use Python? If so check out the FiPy package for Python.

Comment: It looks like A, B, C and D are the xy-coordinates of a rectangle, NX and NY are discretization parameters, FUN is the right hand side function, and BOUND is the Dirichlet boundary data. So I would set the latter to 0 and see what happens. But then again, there is a lot of software with extensive documentation out there, so why guess?

Comment: Have you tried to implement a simple finite difference scheme yourself? It's pretty much the prototypical elliptic PDE, and I'm sure you could find an implementation online if you're not interested in writing one.

Comment: Ok, I will implement finite difference scheme myself. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented finite difference scheme myself and solved resulting linear equations system with octave using embedded methods.